# Interação retorno da Query com Array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php-7

**SQL**:

```
SELECT t.idMembro, t.nomeTabela from (

          SELECT idMembro as idMembro, 'pastores' as  nomeTabela FROM pastores
    union SELECT idLider as idMembro, 'redes'   as  nomeTabela FROM redes
    union SELECT idLider as idMembro, 'regioes' as  nomeTabela FROM regioes
    union SELECT idLider as idMembro, 'areas'   as  nomeTabela FROM areas
    union SELECT idLider as idMembro, 'setores' as  nomeTabela FROM setores
    union SELECT idLider as idMembro, 'celulas' as  nomeTabela FROM celulas
) t
WHERE t.idMembro = " . $_idMembro;
```

Que me dá o seguinte retorno:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora eu tenho o seguinte array de prioridades:

```
$prioridades = array (

    'pastores' => 5,
    'redes'   => 4,
    'regioes' => 3,
    'areas'   => 2,
    'setores'  => 1

);
```

Preciso de ajuda para percorrer a saída da **SQL** e verificar junto ao array prioridades acima qual das saídas tem valor maior e retornar no novo array apenas a linha de maior prioridade.

Tipo:

```
idMembro: 1
nomeTabela: pastores
```

Quem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Por que, ao invés de definir o nome da tabela, você não define a prioridade e já ordena de forma decrescente e retorna apenas o primeiro valor? Assim retornaria [1, 5], mas você sabe que 5 é "pastores".

Comment: Dá pra usar `ORDER BY FIELD(t.nomeTabela, 'pastores', 'redes', 'regioes', 'areas', 'setores')` juntamente com `LIMIT 1`. É o último exemplo [aqui](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by).

Comment: Fernando Savio. Assim está errado? 
      ORDER BY FIELD('pastores', 'redes', 'regioes', 'areas', 'setores') 
      LIMIT 1, ou seja, retirando t.nomeTabela, da clausula ORDER BY. Pois estava dando celulas como maior valor e não pastores